# Adding dynamic variables to an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
    foreach ( $tbl_one_data as $row_ ) {
        $id = ( int ) $row_ [0];
        $time = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [1] );
        $callid = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [2] );
        $queuename = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [3] );

        $arrayValues [] = "($id, '$time','$callid','$queuename',";
    }
}
```

I am trying to improve the above code with the code below:

```
$b = 0;
        foreach ( $tbl_one_data as $row_ ) {
            if ($b < count ( $row_ )) {
                ${"var" . $b} = mysql_escape_string ( $row_ [$b] );
                $b ++;
            }
        }
```

My question is how would I add the dynamic variables created into the array incrementally to achieve something like this: 
`$arrayValues [] = "('$var0','$var1','$var2','$var3'";` ??

`$arrayValues [] = "('${"var" . $b}',";` doesn't seem to have the same effect as in my first code snippet.

Comment: Also, move away from *mysql_* functions and use **mysqli_** or move in to OO PHP with **PDO** . *MySQL_* funtions are ***deprecated*** and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for:

```
foreach ( $tbl_one_data as $row_ ) {
    $arrayValues [] = "('" . implode("','", $row_) . ",";
}
```

All the elements in $row_ are concatenated together into a string by implode() using a comma and single quotes as the "glue".

If this doesn't help or isn't what you wanted, leave a comment and we'll try to get better feedback.

Comment: Surprisingly simple but very effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simply by using below code:

```
foreach ( $tbl_one_data as $row_ ) {
    $newArr = array();
    $newArr[] = ( int ) $row_ [0];
    $newArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [1] );
    $newArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [2] );
    $newArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string ( $row_ [3] );

    $arrayValues [] = $newArr;
}
```